# How to open a new view passing an object as parameter in javaScript - MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two pages, the page A (with its Model) and page B (with its Model), both are loaded by HomeController, as below.

```
public class ModelA
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}

public class ModelB
{

    public ModelB()
    {
        this.A = new ModelA();
    }

    public ModelA A { get; set; }

    public string Local { get; set; }

    public string Destination { get; set; }

}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult PageA()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult PageB(ModelA a)
    {
        ModelB model = new ModelB();

        if (a != null)
        {
            model.A = a;
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

My main page is page A and it calls page B. But, as you can see, the page B is loaded by an object filled in page A. So, the button event click filled the object (type ModelA) and then call page B. The event click in javaScript is:

```
    var obj = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.A))';
    var url = pageA.urlForPageB + "?a=" + obj;      
    window.location.href = url;
```

This event works almost fine. I mean the page B is loaded successfuly but the 'a' object is null. I've also tried:

```
var url = pageA.urlForPageB + "?a=" + $('form#frmPageA').serialize();        
window.location.href = url;
```

And it workd in the same way (the page B is loaded but the 'a' object is null).

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This line,

```
var obj = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.A))';
```

When razor render this line, It genreates an output like this

```
var obj = '{"UserName":"Shyju","UserID":2}';
```

So when we add that as the querystring, It will be finally like this

```
yourSiteName/Home/PageB?a={%22UserName%22:%22Shyju%22,%22UserID%22:2}
```

Model binder will not be able to map this querystring keys and values to an object of ModelA class.

For ModelBinder to map the querystring to a valid object of ModelA, Your querystring should have keys matching to the property names of `ModelA` class. So it should be like

```
/Home/PageB?UserName=Shyju&UserID=2
```

To generate this, we may use the jQuery `$.param` method.  `$.param` will convert a js object to querystring.

This should work.

```
var obj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(yourObjectOfModelA));
var result = $.param(obj);
var url = "@Url.Action("PageB", "Home")?" + result;
window.location.href = url;
```

Always remember that querystrings has a limit (based on browser). So sending a full object via querystring will not always work, for lighter smaller objects( like above), It will work.